# Swing element animation on hover

Tags: jquery, css, animation

My goal is to swing an item only on hover, by using CSS and some jQuery (and of course should stop on mouse out).

Searching the internet I found the code to swing an element when the document is ready ([complete jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFH9c/)).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function swing(){
        $('.swing').toggleClass('right');
        setTimeout(swing, 1000);
    }
    swing();
});
```

I tried using the .hover() method, but seems to not work.
How can I fix this minor problem?

Comment: only css https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/05/8-simple-css3-transitions-that-will-wow-your-users/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var id;
    function swing(){
        $('.swing').toggleClass('right');
        id = setTimeout(swing, 1000);
    }
    $(".swing").hover(function() {
        swing();
    },
    function() {
        clearTimeout(id);
    });
});
```